# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort won't behave like PuTTY

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, putty, at-command

I recently purchased a modem, which attaches via USB and appears to the operating system as a serial port device: COM19

To ensure the modem was OK, I first tried using PuTTY in serial mode. From there, I have no problem issuing AT commands and receiving responses from the modem. According to PuTTY configuration, my default options for controlling local serial lines are (at the time):

- Speed (baud): 9600
- Data bits: 8
- Stop bits: 1
- Parity: None
- Flow control: XON/XOFF

Here's what I see in PuTTY (when I type the AT command):

```
AT
OK

^BOOT:30645964,0,0,0,75
```

However, when I try to access the same COM port from .NET (not at the same time as running PuTTY) I never receive the "OK" responses. I do still receive (what appears to be) echo, and the occasional unsolicited message from the modem, so I can see that I'm connected to the correct device. Sometimes the modem will respond to a malformed command with "ERROR", but never "OK". Here's the C# snippet where I initialize the COM port:

```
var commandPort = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
commandPort.DataReceived += CommandPort_DataReceived;
commandPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
commandPort.Open();

commandPort.Write("AT\n");
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

And this is the event handler:

```
private static void CommandPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write(((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting());
}
```

This is what's printed back to the console of the C# application (note that I'm not explicitly writing the command to the console, it's added by the CommandPort_DataReceived event handler):

```
AT

^BOOT:30645964,0,0,0,75
```

None of the AT commands issued by the .NET application perform any action, though their equivalents in PuTTY are able to query modem state, place calls, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SerialPort` class's `NewLine` property. By default it's set to "\n". This needs to be "\r", then you can use the `WriteLine(...)` method to send AT commands.

```
commandPort.NewLine = "\r";
commandPort.Open();

commandPort.WriteLine("AT");
```